# Confusion of javadoc on `Class.getDeclaredMethod`

Tags: java, reflection, overloading

`Class.getDeclaredMethod` has following javadoc.

> If this Class object represents a type that has multiple declared
>   methods with **the same name and parameter types, but different return
>   types**, then the returned array has a Method object for each such
>   method.

I know that we can't overload a method has same name and parameter types. So what does this doc mean?

Comment: This can happen with compiler-synthesised bridge methods for Generics.

Comment: I believe it can also happen with other JVM languages, though I don't know which.

Comment: @EJP No. Bridge methods have different arguments type. Synthetic methods always follow the method specification, unless you write bytecode manually.

Comment: @Andreas I believe too... But write these confused sentence into **java**doc only for other language seems a bit too unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [EJP said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421718/confusion-of-javadoc-on-class-getdeclaredmethod?noredirect=1#comment85844881_49421718):

> This can happen with compiler-synthesised bridge methods for Generics.

Actually, it not just for generics.

Any time a subclass overrides a method using a different return type, the compiler creates a synthetic bridge method.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
public class Super {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (Method method : Sub.class.getDeclaredMethods())
            System.out.println(method + (method.isSynthetic() ? " **SYNTHETIC**" : ""));
    }
    public Number get() {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}
class Sub extends Super {
    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
public java.lang.Integer Sub.get()
public java.lang.Number Sub.get() **SYNTHETIC**
```

Comment: 1+ *subclass overrides a method using a different return type* this is called covariant return types, and these are the only two cases where this can happen AFAIK